# How do I make an onclick event that would close/open all instances of a specific class on the page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know this would involve Jquery, I am not as learned as I'd like to be in mocking this up myself. I know there is a toggle function, but dont know how I'd mock this up for my own use.

This might be possible in css3 too? But Im guessing Jquery would be a better cross browser solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a button, or other element, with a specific `id`:

```
$('#id').click(
    function(){
        $('.className').toggle();
    });
```

Or, to be a little prettier:

```
$('#id').click(
    function(){
        $('.className').fadeToggle();
        /* or:
        $('.className').slideToggle();
        */
    });
```

This is, given some fairly specific mark-up constraints and *low* cross-browser compatibility requirements, possible in CSS, albeit only in CSS3:

HTML:

```
​<a href="#show">Show all</a>
    <div id="show">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <a href="#">hide</a>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 0;
}
div > a {
    opacity: 0;
}
div:target a {
    opacity: 1;
}

div > ​div {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000;
    border-radius: 1em 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

div:target > div​ {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-width: 2px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TQPuk/).

The above can be adapted to apply, of course, to specific classes rather than *all* `div` elements, and this is *one* (though perhaps not the *only*) way to work with specific classes, using the general sibling combinator `~`:

HTML:

```
<a href="#show">Show all</a>
<a href="#firstOne">Show all '.one' elements</a>
<a href="#firstTwo">Show all '.two' elements</a>
<div id="show">
    <div></div>
    <div id="firstOne" class="one"></div>
    <div id="firstTwo" class="two"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <a href="#">hide</a>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 0;
}
div > a {
    opacity: 0;
}
div:target a {
    opacity: 1;
}

div > div {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000;
    border-radius: 1em 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

div:target > div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-width: 2px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

div:target > .one,
.one {
    background-color: #ffa;
}

div:target > .two,
.two {
    background-color: #f90;
}

.one:target,
.one:target ~ .one {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-width: 2px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

.two:target,
.two:target ~ .two {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-width: 2px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TQPuk/1/).

Bear in mind, though, that CSS selection can only select elements that appear *later* in the DOM, so to show *all* the `div` elements of `class="one"` the `target` for the link *has* to be the *first* element of that `class`, so, to be concise, the target *has* to be, literally, the `#firstOne`. Hence the name, really, but it seemed worth specifying that.

References:

- [`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/).
- [General Sibling combinators, and `:target` pseudo-class, at the W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).
- [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: +1 for aiming a little higher with the low-hanging fruit question. :)

Comment: I only really posted because I thought of the CSS solution; but it took longer than I expected to work through it (for some unknown reason)... =)

Comment: You're *very* welcome, I'm glad to have been of help! =D I'm also somewhat (*ridiculously*) proud at how cool the CSS option is..! Oh, and if your question's been answered please consider [accepting the answer that best helped you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) solve your problem. =)

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
$(button).click(function(){
    $('.yourclassname').toggle();
});
```

Here is some documentation on the `jQuery.toggle` function : http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you'd do it in css3 but in jquery you use the class selector (".class").

Comment: In CSS3? Well, to do it in CSS3 is crazy-awkward! But, to quote Simba, strangely satisfying..! =)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myclass').on('click', function() { $(this).slideToggle('fast'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).click(function(){


   $("element_to_delete").toggle();


});
```

If you want to Hide/Show